# Back Button Color in iOS

Tags: mobile, iphone, ios, back-button

Why exactly is it that I'm not finding very many examples of a Back button being different color from the app background?

Is there somekind of a rule in place?

I proposed using a black Back button with white text in the predominantly red background application and got "not standard in iOS" response from the development team...

Answer (score 3):

I think you should give the [Apple User Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/MobileHIG.pdf) a read.

> **Consistency**
>
> Consistency in the interface allows people to transfer their knowledge and skills from one application to
>   another. A consistent application is not a slavish copy of other applications. Rather, it is an application that
>   takes advantage of the standards and paradigms people are comfortable with.
>   To determine whether an app follows the principle of consistency, think about these questions:
>
> ● Is the application consistent with iOS standards? Does it use system-provided controls, views, and icons
>   correctly? Does it incorporate device features in a reliable way?
>
> ● Is the application consistent within itself? Does text use uniform terminology and style? Do the same
>   icons always mean the same thing? Can people predict what will happen when they perform the same
>   action in different places? Do custom UI elements look and behave the same throughout the app?
>
> ● Within reason, is the application consistent with its earlier versions? Have the ter

Also Page 55,

> **Use UI Elements Consistently**
>
> People expect standard views and controls to look and behave consistently across applications.
>
> Follow the recommended usages for standard user interface elements. In this way, users can depend on
>   their prior experience to help them as they learn to use your application. You also make it easy for your app
>   to look up-to-date and work correctly if iOS changes the look or behavior of these standard views or controls.
>
> For an app that enables an immersive task, such as a game, it’s reasonable to create completely custom
>   controls.
>
> This is because you’re creating a unique environment, and discovering how to control that
>   environment is an experience users expect in such applications.
>   Avoid radically changing the appearance of a control that performs a standard action. If you use unfamiliar
>   controls to perform standard actions, users will spend time discovering how to use them and will wonder
>   what, if anything, your controls do that the standard ones do not.
>   iOS makes available to you many of the standard buttons and icons used throughout the built-in applications.
>   For example, you can use the same Refresh, Organize, Trash, Reply, and Compose icons that Mail uses on
>   both iPhone and iPad.
>
> To avoid confusing people, never use the standard buttons and icons to mean something else. Be sure
>   you understand the documented meaning of a standard button or icon; don’t rely on your interpretation of
>   its appearance. To learn more about using system-provided items, see “System-Provided Buttons and
>   Icons” (page 135).
>
> In addition to the benefit of leveraging users’ prior experience, using system-provided buttons and icons
>   imparts two other substantial advantages:
>
> ● Decreased development time, because you don’t have to create custom art to represent standard
>   functions

Comment: ahh, yes...the sharepoint design guidelines resurrected!